# How to get SymPy to simplify (B*x)^a*(C*x)^-a into (B/C)^a?

Tags: python, sympy

I have the following code:

```
(Symbol('B')*Symbol('x'))**Symbol('a') * (Symbol('C')*Symbol('x'))**-Symbol('a')
```

which is not being simplified, i.e., the x isn't cancelling out. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Looks I need to use `powsimp` with `force=True`:

```
powsimp((Symbol('B')*Symbol('x'))**Symbol('a') * 
        (Symbol('C')*Symbol('x'))**-Symbol('a'), 
    force=True)
```

yields `(B/C)^a`.

Answer (score 0):

This suggests to me that the parser is having trouble interpreting the minus sign in front of the second exponent.

It's easy for a human reader to miss it, too.

I'd recommend writing it this way:

```
(Symbol('B')*Symbol('x'))**Symbol('a') / (Symbol('C')*Symbol('x'))**Symbol('a')
```

Your intent is clearer that way.

Comment: No need to be indignant.  No, I did not try any code.  You have a solution with your force.